# Trying to open a csv file in xamarin

Tags: android, csv, xamarin

I have a project in which I fill text fields and store them into a CSV that is then saved in the mobile phone. I created a listview that shows every csv file that has been created, and when I click on an item, I want to open the csv file. Everything works, except it doesn't open the file.

```
        string directory = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + Java.IO.File.Separator + "Pharmastock";
        string[] fichiers = Directory.GetFiles(directory); 
        ArrayAdapter<string> fichiersAdapter;
        fichiersAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, fichiers);



        ListView listehisto = new ListView(this);
        view.AddView(listehisto);

        listehisto.SetAdapter(fichiersAdapter);

        listehisto.ItemClick += Listehisto_ItemClick;

        void Listehisto_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = fichiersAdapter.GetItem(e.Position);
            File.Open(item, FileMode.Open);
        }

        this.SetContentView(view);
```

I'm not using xamarin.forms.
Thanks

Comment: how do you know that it doesn't open the file?  You're calling File.Open but not doing anything with the stream that it returns.

Comment: Oh ok I thought it would literally open the file with an app. What should I do then ? I want it to open in a csv application such as office excel. I tried some solutions but none of them seemed to work for me, or I didn't know how to make it work properly